# R: Extract rows from a dataframe where values from one column occur in a separate vector

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe `uniprotconvert` which has two columns, `uniprotconvert$V1` and `uniprotconvert$V2`. I wish to extract only those rows of this dataframe where the value in `V2` is occurs in a separate vector, `genelist`.

Here is a construction of what these dataframes could potentially look like:

```
uniprotconvert:

       V1     V2
1  P62258 P62258
2  P62258  YWHAE
3  P31947 P31947
4  P31947    SFN
5  P31947   HME1
6  P31946 P31946
7  P31946  YWHAB
8  P27348 P27348
9  P27348  YWHAQ
10 P61981 P61981

genelist <- c("YWHAE", "HSBDS", "YWAB", "P27348", "KCG",
              "DHABD", "P28736", "SFN", "P36718", "P93718")
```

Result of Extraction:

```
       V1     V2
2  P62258  YWHAE
4  P31947    SFN
8  P27348 P27348
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `uniprotconvert[uniprotconvert$V2 %in% genelist,]`

Comment: Yep.  But there should only be three rows in the result I think

Comment: Just for fun, you could also try `data.table`s binary search (if you have a big data) `library(data.table) ; setkey(setDT(uniprotconvert), V2)[genelist, nomatch = 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uniprotconvert[ uniprotconvert$V2 %in% genelist, ]
```

Will do the job.